# Trying to remove a previously inserted shape object

Tags: excel, vba

The following code successfully inserts a line with arrowheads and adds left and right cell edge borders in a set of merged cells the number of which is determined by the variable, p_length:

```
'Add length dimension arrows/lines  
Set Top_Line = Range(Cells(4, 20), Cells(4, 20 + p_length - 1))
Worksheets("Drawing").Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 
Top_Line.Left, Top_Line.Top + (Top_Line.Height / 2), Top_Line.Left + 
Top_Line.width, _
Top_Line.Top + (Top_Line.Height / 2)).Select

With Selection
    With .ShapeRange.Line
         .EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
         .BeginArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
         .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End With
End With

Worksheets("Drawing").Range("T4").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = 
xlContinuous
Worksheets("Drawing").Range(Cells(4, 20), Cells(4, 20 + p_length - 
1)).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Worksheets("Drawing").Range(Cells(4, 20), Cells(4, 20 + p_length - 1)).Merge
```

I've tried the following code to remove them.  It successfully removes the cell edge borders and unmerges the cells but the arrowed line doesn't get removed.  What do I need to change please?

```
'Remove length dimension arrows/lines
Worksheets("Drawing").Range(Cells(4, 20), Cells(4, 20 + p_length - 1)).Clear
Worksheets("Drawing").Range(Cells(4, 20), Cells(4, 20 + p_length - 1)).UnMerge
```

---

OK. Here's all of the revised sub code with the additions as suggested:

```
Sub DrawPontoon_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim p_length, p_width As Integer
    Dim Top_Line As Range
    Dim Side_Line As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Drawing")

With ws

    'Get Pontoon Length and Width sizes
    p_length = Range("pontoon_Length").Value ' pontoon_Length is the name allocated to Pontoon Length Cell in Drawing Worksheet
    p_width = Range("pontoon_Width").Value   ' pontoon_Width is the name allocated to Pontoon Width in Drawing Worksheet
    'MsgBox "Length is " & p_length & ", Width is " & p_width

    'Draw pontoon by copying the image located at Named Cell P31 (Double_Float_Picture) and paste it into each cell in defined range
    .Range("Double_Float_Picture").Copy .Range(Cells(6, 20), Cells(6 + p_width - 1, 20 + p_length - 1))

    'Add length dimension line
    Set Top_Line = Range(Cells(4, 20), Cells(4, 20 + p_length - 1))
    .Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, Top_Line.Left + 2, Top_Line.Top + (Top_Line.Height / 2), Top_Line.Left + Top_Line.Width - 2, _
    Top_Line.Top + (Top_Line.Height / 2)).Select

    ' Make arrows and color black
    With Selection
        With .ShapeRange.Line
             .EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
             .BeginArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
             .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
       End With
       ' Attempt to apply name to shape so that it can be deleted by name
       ' when required
        Dim MyShape As Shape
        Set MyShape = Selection ' **Get type mismatch error here**
        MyShape.Name = "Dim_Line"
    End With

    'Add length line cell borders
    .Range(Cells(4, 20), Cells(4, 20)).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Range(Cells(4, 20), Cells(4, 20 + p_length - 1)).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Range(Cells(4, 20), Cells(4, 20 + p_length - 1)).Merge

    'Add length dimension
    .Range(Cells(3, 20), Cells(3, 20 + p_length - 1)).Merge
    .Range(Cells(3, 20), Cells(3, 20)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Range(Cells(3, 20), Cells(3, 20)).Formula = "=RoundUp((D38), 1) & "" m"""

    'Add width dimension line
    Set Side_Line = Range(Cells(6, 20 + p_length + 1), Cells(6 + p_width - 1, 20 + p_length + 1))
    .Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, Side_Line.Left + (Side_Line.Width / 2), Side_Line.Top + 2, Side_Line.Left + (Side_Line.Width / 2), _
    Side_Line.Top + Side_Line.Height - 2).Select

    ' Make arrows and color black
    With Selection
        With .ShapeRange.Line
            .EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
            .BeginArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
    End With

    'Add width line cell borders
    Dim widthLineAddr As String
    widthLineAddr = Cells(6, 20 + p_length + 1).Address & ":" & Cells(6 + p_width - 1, 20 + p_length + 1).Address
    .Range(widthLineAddr).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Range(widthLineAddr).Borders(xlBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Range(widthLineAddr).Merge


    'Add width dimension
    Dim widthDimensionAddr As String
    widthDimensionAddr = Cells(6, 20 + p_length + 2).Address & ":" & Cells(6 + p_width - 1, 20 + p_length + 2).Address
    .Range(widthDimensionAddr).Merge
    .Range(widthDimensionAddr).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Range(widthDimensionAddr).Orientation = xlDownward
    .Range(widthDimensionAddr).Formula = "=RoundUp((D39), 1) & "" m"""

End With

MsgBox "Drawing complete"
End Sub
```

I have attempted to give a name (Dim_Line) to the selection as suggested but get a "Type mismatch" error at the line - Set MyShape = Selection.  If the Selection is really a shape then why the error?

Comment: `Set MyShape = Selection.ShapeRange`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved after finding this post https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/15946-deleting-a-line from 2004!

Did away with the .Select and instead set the lines to shapes (shpLength and shpWidth) and then gave these names (lShapeName and wShapeName).

```
Sub DrawPontoon_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim p_length, p_width As Integer
Dim Top_Line As Range
Dim Side_Line As Range
Dim shpLength, shpWidth As Shape
Dim lShapeName, wShapeName As String

Set ws = Worksheets("Drawing")

With ws

'Get Pontoon Length and Width sizes
p_length = Range("pontoon_Length").Value ' pontoon_Length is the name allocated to Pontoon Length Cell in Drawing Worksheet
p_width = Range("pontoon_Width").Value   ' pontoon_Width is the name allocated to Pontoon Width in Drawing Worksheet
'MsgBox "Length is " & p_length & ", Width is " & p_width

'Draw pontoon by copying the image located at Named Cell P31 (Double_Float_Picture) and paste it into each cell in defined range
.Range("Double_Float_Picture").Copy .Range(Cells(6, 20), Cells(6 + p_width - 1, 20 + p_length - 1))

'Add length dimension line
Set Top_Line = Range(Cells(4, 20), Cells(4, 20 + p_length - 1))
Set shpLength = .Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, Top_Line.Left + 2, Top_Line.Top + (Top_Line.Height / 2), Top_Line.Left + Top_Line.Width - 2, _
Top_Line.Top + (Top_Line.Height / 2)) 'Modified here: Removed .Select

' Make arrows and color black
        On Error Resume Next
         With shpLength
            .Name = "LengthLine" 'Assign name to enable later deletion
            .Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
            .Line.BeginArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
            .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Add length line cell borders
.Range(Cells(4, 20), Cells(4, 20)).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Range(Cells(4, 20), Cells(4, 20 + p_length - 1)).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Range(Cells(4, 20), Cells(4, 20 + p_length - 1)).Merge

'Add length dimension
.Range(Cells(3, 20), Cells(3, 20 + p_length - 1)).Merge
.Range(Cells(3, 20), Cells(3, 20)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
.Range(Cells(3, 20), Cells(3, 20)).Formula = "=RoundUp((D38), 1) & "" m"""

'Add width dimension line
Set Side_Line = Range(Cells(6, 20 + p_length + 1), Cells(6 + p_width - 1, 20 + p_length + 1))
Set shpWidth = .Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, Side_Line.Left + (Side_Line.Width / 2), Side_Line.Top + 2, Side_Line.Left + (Side_Line.Width / 2), _
Side_Line.Top + Side_Line.Height - 2) ' Modified here: Removed .Select

' Make arrows and color black
On Error Resume Next
         With shpWidth
            .Name = "WidthLine" ' Assign name to enable later deletion
            .Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
            .Line.BeginArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
            .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Add width line cell borders
Dim widthLineAddr As String
widthLineAddr = Cells(6, 20 + p_length + 1).Address & ":" & Cells(6 + p_width - 1, 20 + p_length + 1).Address
.Range(widthLineAddr).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Range(widthLineAddr).Borders(xlBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Range(widthLineAddr).Merge


'Add width dimension
Dim widthDimensionAddr As String
widthDimensionAddr = Cells(6, 20 + p_length + 2).Address & ":" & Cells(6 + p_width - 1, 20 + p_length + 2).Address
.Range(widthDimensionAddr).Merge
.Range(widthDimensionAddr).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
.Range(widthDimensionAddr).Orientation = xlDownward
.Range(widthDimensionAddr).Formula = "=RoundUp((D39), 1) & "" m"""

End With

MsgBox "Drawing complete"
End Sub
```

To delete the lines then used:

```
    'Remove length dimension line
    lShapeName = "LengthLine"
    On Error Resume Next
    Shapes(lShapeName).Delete

    'Remove width dimension line
     wShapeName = "WidthLine"
    On Error Resume Next
    Shapes(wShapeName).Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a `Name` to the `Shape`, you can delete it by `Name`.  So after:

```
Worksheets("Drawing").Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 
     Top_Line.Left, Top_Line.Top + (Top_Line.Height / 2), Top_Line.Left + 
     Top_Line.width, _
     Top_Line.Top + (Top_Line.Height / 2)).Select
```

include something like:

```
Dim MyShape as Shape
Set MyShape = Selection
MyShape.Name = "whatever"
```

Then if you later want to delete the Shape, use:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("whatever").Delete
```

Comment: Thanks but after adding suggested code I get a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch at Set MyShape = Selection

Comment: Still having problems. I've added my revised code to my original post.  It's the complete sub and has the additions suggested but still errors.

Comment: `Set MyShape = Selection.ShapeRange`

Comment: Tried @MarcoMarc suggestion but still get mismatch error.